# POSIX Vector Comparison -- searching through and finding a match between DATE vectors efficiently?

Tags: r, datetime, date, matching

I have 5five `POSIXct` type vectors.  `ptime` vector is the reference vector.  I want to find matching dates between `ptime` and the rest of the vectors.  Once a date is matched then I want to perform a time comparison.  A time comparison is followed and the the results are populated in a `data.frame(test)` with an appropriate classifying number.

```
# create the reference and the other vectors 
ptime <- sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2005-08-01'),as.POSIXct('2006-05-31'), by='hour'),1051)
dawn <- sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2005-01-01'),as.POSIXct('2007-12-31'),by='hour'),1095)
sunrise <- sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2005-01-01'),as.POSIXct('2007-12-31'),by='hour'),1095)
sunset <- sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2005-01-01'),as.POSIXct('2007-12-31'),by='hour'),1095)
dusk <- sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2005-01-01'),as.POSIXct('2007-12-31'),by='hour'),1095)

# extract the date to compare using only the `dawn` vector
# all other vectors (except ptime) have the same date and length
pt <- as.Date(ptime)
dw <- as.Date(dawn)

# create data.frame
time <- c(1:1051)
test<-data.frame(time)

# I use a data.frame because I want to re-populate an existing data.frame
> str(test)
'data.frame':   1051 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ time: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...

# this is the loop that matches and assigns
for( b in 1:length(ptime) ){
    for( a in 1:length(dawn) ) {
      if( dw[a] == pt[b] ){
            if( ptime[b] < dawn[a] ) {
                test$time[b] <- 1
            }else if( ptime[b] < sunrise[a] ) {
                test$time[b] <- 2
            }else if( ptime[b] < sunset[a] ) {
                test$time[b] <- 3
            }else if( ptime[b] < dusk[a] ) {
                test$time[b] <- 4
            }else
                test$time[b] <- 1
        }
    }
}

# output result shows the categorization sequence of 1, 2, 3, and 4
> head(test)
  time
1    1
2    1
3    3
4    1
5    1
6    3
```

The above code accomplishes what I want to do... but it takes `98.58` seconds.  I have more data that varies in length (up to 5000).

Since I am a newbie to this, my guess is... what is taking so much time is the comparison of the DATES.  Every time a new comparison has to be made `dw[a] == pt[b]` the process must search through `dw[a]`.  Also, are the `if-else` statements necessary to accomplish the task?

Can anyone provide a faster/more efficient method to `loop` through, find matches, and store the results?
Greatly appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Your code is not reproducible, in other words I get errors when I run it on my machine.  Please make your example reproducible.

Comment: Edited my post.  Example code should work.  Thanks

Comment: Please try again.  To ensure your example is reproducible, start from a clean R session and try to run your code.

Comment: there we go.  sorry about that

Answer (score 3):

*Edited based on OP's updates*

What follows is still mainly guesswork on my part. I fixed some typos in your edit to get this:

```
ptime <- sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2005-08-01'),as.POSIXct('2006-05-31'), 
                by='hour'),1051)
dawn <- sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2005-01-01'),as.POSIXct('2007-12-31'),
                by='hour'),1095)
sunrise <- sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2005-01-01'),as.POSIXct('2007-12-31'),
                by='hour'),1095)
sunset <- sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2005-01-01'),as.POSIXct('2007-12-31'),
                by='hour'),1095)
dusk <- sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2005-01-01'),as.POSIXct('2007-12-31'),
                by='hour'),1095)

# extract the date to compare using only the `dawn` vector
# all other vectors (except ptime) have the same date and length
pt <- as.Date(ptime)
dw <- as.Date(dawn)

# create data.frame
time <- c(1:1051)
test<-data.frame(time)
```

Here's my wild stab at this:

```
tmp <- outer(pt, dw, "==")
tmp[upper.tri(tmp)] <- NA
tmp <- which(tmp,arr.ind = TRUE)

test$time[ tmp[ ptime[ tmp[,1] ] < dawn[ tmp[,2] ],1] ] <- 1
test$time[ tmp[ ptime[ tmp[,1] ] < sunrise[ tmp[,2] ],1 ] ] <- 2
test$time[ tmp[ ptime[ tmp[,1] ] < sunset[ tmp[,2] ],1 ] ] <- 3
test$time[ tmp[ ptime[ tmp[,1] ] < dusk[ tmp[,2] ],1] ] <- 4
```

That's some ugly, ugly subset indexing going on there. Ugly enough that I'm convinced there has to be a better way to organize your data to avoid this. It's also obscure enough that I'm not sure I can clearly explain what's going on, but I *think* this is doing what you describe.

Comment: Sorry for not posting reproducible data but it seems like you have done it quite simply.  The only thing I would of done differently would of been to offset the dates `x <- sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2000-08-01'),as.POSIXct('2003-12-31'),by = "hour"),1000)` and `y <- sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2000-01-01'),as.POSIXct('2005-12-31'),by = "hour"),5000)` and create different lengths.  The resulting data is stored into a dataframe `test$time`, what other 'convenient' form would you recommend?  I'm still learning and I greatly appreciate you sharing your knowledge

Comment: Also... sunrise, sunset, etc. are POSIXct date/time vectors as well with the same DATE as `dawn`

Comment: joran... running the `if-else` statement you posted throws an error... `In if (x[d[, 1]] < y[d[, 2]]) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Comment: @wisfool That's why I said the code I provided was only a _sketch_. If you want more help, you'll have to edit your question to include a self-contained, reproducible example. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for some advice on how to do this.

Comment: @joranThe sample data you provided is exactly the same type of data I am working with `POSIXct` except the years are 2005-2007 for `x` and 2005-2006 for `y` with the above given lengths. `x <- sample(seq(as.POSIXct( '2005-01- 01'), as.POSIXct('2007-12-31')),1095)`, `y <- sample(seq (as.POSIXct('2005-01-01'),as.POSIXct('2006-16-31'),1051)`, `z <- sample(seq(as.POSIXct( '2005-01- 01'), as.POSIXct('2007-12-31')) ,1095)`.  Everything you have done is in direct comparison to my data.  You reproduced the problem I was having problems with.

Comment: @joran...continued... I don't understand what you mean by 'reproducible example' when you reproduced exactly what I have (with minor details).  Your method is extremely fast (0.96 !!) !!  I had to adjust the `if-else` statement due to the above mentioned error but other than that I thank you greatly for your help.  I'll be dissecting your method for days until I understand the logic.  Thanks again!

Comment: @joran... basically what this is trying to do is take a given event with a timestamp (`ptime`) and label it when it occurred i.e. dawn, sunrise, sunset, dusk, or night.  The data for dawn, sunrise, etc. comprises of a starting timestamp, when it happens (for example, dawn happens at '2005-01-01 04:25:00').  In order to label `ptime` i first match dates of occurrence.  Then I check the time of `ptime` and compare it with the other times to label it appropriately.  If `ptime` happened before 'dawn', then `ptime` is labeled night, the `ptime` event was recorded during the night.

Comment: @joran... Thank you for your attention and help.  With the help of your code I was able to accomplish the task extremely quickly... this is what I have... `d <- which(outer(as.Date(ptime, tz='MST'),as.Date(dawn, tz='MST'),"=="),arr.ind = TRUE)
test$time  <- ifelse(
    (ptime[d[,1]] < dawn[d[,2]]) | (ptime[d[,1]] > dusk[d[,2]]),  1, 
    ifelse(
        ptime[d[,1]] < sunrise[d[,2]],  2, 
        ifelse(
            ptime[d[,1]] < sunset[d[,2]],  3,  4 ) ) )`

Comment: @wisfool: please post this solution as an answer.  It's OK, in fact encouraged, to answer your own question if you come up with a good solution.  (Much easier for future readers to find than something at the bottom of a long comment thread ...)

Answer (score 2):

**Real fast solution**

```
ptime <- sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2005-08-01'),as.POSIXct('2006-05-31'), by='hour'),1051)
dawn <- sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2005-01-01'),as.POSIXct('2007-12-31')),1095)
sunrise <- sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2005-01-01'),as.POSIXct('2007-12-31')),1095)
sunset <- sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2005-01-01'),as.POSIXct('2007-12-31')),1095)
dusk <- sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2005-01-01'),as.POSIXct('2007-12-31')),1095)

time <- c(1:1051)
test<-data.frame(time)

# From joran
#creates a matrix that lists the IDs that match each other
d <- which(outer(as.Date(ptime, tz='MST'),as.Date(dawn, tz='MST'),"=="),arr.ind = TRUE)

>head(d)
     row col
[1,]  86 213
[2,] 226 213
[3,] 346 213
[4,] 492 214
[5,] 272 215

#This `ifelse` handles multivalued vectors
test$time <- ifelse( (ptime[d[,1]] < dawn[d[,2]]) | (ptime[d[,1]] > dusk[d[,2]]), 1, 
             ifelse(ptime[d[,1]] < sunrise[d[,2]], 2, 
             ifelse( ptime[d[,1]] < sunset[d[,2]], 3, 4 ) ) )
```

Thanks to joran this runs at `0.00` per my machine.  Vectorization is the key.